# Race condition when reading from /dev/pts/x

Tags: linux, bash, linux-kernel, race-condition, tty

I read in [this article](https://dev.to/napicella/linux-terminals-tty-pty-and-shell-192e) that when a process reads from a tty device, say `/dev/pts/1`, the tty driver/line discipline (when in cooked mode) buffers the data, and only when `enter` is pressed, the data is passed to the process. I ran the following experiment:

I open a terminal, and note the tty it's using. Let's say it's `/dev/pts/0`. 
Now I open another terminal, using `/dev/pts/1` for the sake of the manner, and run a process, which only executes the following function:

```
// passing /dev/pts/0 to the function

int read_from_tty(char *tty)
{
    int bytes_read = 0;
    int fd = 0;
    char buffer[100];
    
    fd = open(tty, O_RDWR);
    if(-1 == fd)
    {
        printf("Couldn't open pts\n");
        
        return 1;
    }
    printf("File opened: %d\n", fd);
    
    while(1)
    {
        bytes_read = read(fd, buffer, 100);
        if(-1 == bytes_read)
        {
            perror("read");
        }
        if(-1 == write(1, buffer, bytes_read))
        {
            perror("write:");
        }
        memset(buffer, 0, 100);
    }
}
```

Now I start typing characters in the `/dev/pts/0` terminal, and I see that characters are appearing mostly in the `/dev/pts/1` terminal, but one in something like 10 chars I see a char in the `/dev/pts/0` terminal.

If what's written in the article is true, seemingly, the characters should have been buffered in the line discipline, and only when I press enter be passed to one of the reading processes (assuming the `bash` is just sitting blocked on `read`).

Could someone explain?

### EDIT

Examining this a bit further. I add the following line to the code above:

```
...
bytes_read = read(fd, buffer, 100);
if(-1 == bytes_read)
{
    perror("read");
}
printf("Bytes read: %d\n", bytes_read);
if(-1 == write(1, buffer, bytes_read))
{
...
```

I can see that when I read `/dev/pts/0`, it only reads 1 byte at a time. Whereas, if I run it with `/dev/pts/1` (actually reading from stdin), it does read a whole line.
Could someone explain?

Comment: And the reason you added a `bash` tag to your question?

Comment: @LéaGris: bash tag is justified here as it is running on one terminal during the experiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `bash` sets the terminal in non canonical mode when reading from the terminal and when it gets an end of line, it sets back the terminal in canonical mode to run the command line.

The same experience can be done with two terminals:

- Terminal#1 (/dev/pts/6): launch `strace /bin/bash`
- Terminal#2: launch  `strace cat /dev/pts/6`

The bash shell on terminal#1 deactivates the canonical mode and calls *pselect()* to wait for the input:

```
$ strace /bin/bash
[...]
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
[...]
pselect6(1, [0], NULL, NULL, NULL, {[], 8}
```

On terminal#2, the `cat` command merely calls a blocking *read()* to get chars from the terminal:

```
$ strace cat /dev/pts/6
[...]
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/pts/6", O_RDONLY) = 3
[...]
read(3,
```

So, both `bash` and `cat` are reading concurrently on the terminal. When we type characters in terminal#1, *pselect()* returns to indicate that a character is available and then `bash` calls a blocking *read()* to get the char. But the concurrent *read()* from `cat` stills the characters between the calls to *pselect()* and *read()* by `bash`. Sometimes, `bash` is able to get a character before `cat`.

Here is an example where *pselect()* returns because a character is available (I typed "Y") and a following *read()* is called to get it on terminal#1:

```
pselect6(1, [0], NULL, NULL, NULL, {[], 8}) = 1 (in [0])
read(0,
```

But *read()* from `cat` on the other terminal succeeded to get the character before the *read()* of `bash`:

```
write(1, "Y", 1Y)                        = 1
read(3,
```

Sometimes, `bash` is able to get the typed character before `cat`. Generally, when it is blocked on its *read()* call (that is to say it missed the character detected by *pselect()* but it will be able to get one of the subsequent typed characters before one of the calls to *read()* by `cat`)...

**Side note**

When we launch `stty -a` under bash, the display shows that the terminal is in canonical mode:

```
$ stty -a
[...]
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

This is because of the fact that `bash` reactivates the canonical mode before launching the `stty` command.

Comment: If bash sets the terminal in canonical mode, why when I type `stty -a` I see the `icanon` flag?

Comment: This is a common trap : stty is launched as a command by bash. So, bash reactivates icanon before launching stty